# Find the call function of a string

Tags: x86

On a 16bit real mode x86 program I can locate a string that is displayed on screen. How do I go about finding all the places this string is called from to trace back the "print" function?

Comment: Have you tried pressing `x` in IDA when this string is selected?

Comment: @bart1e no cross references listed for ANY strings. Even ones that I know get displayed. As this in an embeded rom I also cant press c at the reset vector either so a lot of the auto eploring doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @uMinded When you are analysing dynamically you can try a hardware breakpoint on the string - this won't give "all the places", but probably some interesting starting points

Comment: In the past I was able to use W32Dasm to find string references for a similar binary when IDA and Ghidra failed (select Refs -> String Data References).

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for `INT 10h`, that's the x86 BIOS interrupt that allows you to output text to the screen, as well as change the video mode and cursor position among other things.

Comment: I should have mentioned its an embeded rom so not a standard bios. I am trying to track down this exact call idea though.

Comment: @uMinded agreed, and moreover you should edit this into your question. These are the things anyone willing to assist needs to even attempt to help.